# Delete folders with wild cards from a batch file Windows 7

Tags: batch-file, command, command-prompt

1. I know we can write programs to do it.
2. I know we can write other scripts (perl/vbscript/ etc.) to do it.

I am looking for a command prompt/batch file solution to delete all folders matching **sub_*** (like sub_1, sub_2 ... ) to be deleted. rmdir or rd doesn't support wildcards, and I'm not able to figure out how to pipe the output of **dir sub_*/ad** command to **delete** command one by one as well. Any loop syntax etc. I can use?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
for /d %x in (sub_*) do rd /s /q "%x"
```

You need to double the `%` if used in a batch file:

```
for /d %%x in (sub_*) do rd /s /q "%%x"
```

Untested, make sure to first use `echo` or something else that doesn't immediately wipe the directories ;)

Comment: Yup! Works perfectly! I had seen some people were using %%f in the for loop for files, but I didn't know what to use for directories. From where do we look this kind of information?

Comment: @Piyush: The variable name is not important. The `/D` tells `for` to look for directories.

Comment: Ah ... Now I know ... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`forfiles /P C:\where\my\dirs\at /M sub_* /C "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE rmdir /s /q @file"`